# Pasar datos de un DataGridview a otro DataGridview enlazados a Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

Hola necesito que me ayuden con un programa que estoy un poco trabado ya que no se como hacer para pasar filas de un datagrid a otro que estan enlazados a una base de datos en Access. La aplicacion la estoy haciendo en visual C#[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pongo una imagen del form con los dos datagrids. Del primer DataGrid llamado GridCarro tengo que pasar los datos al segundo DataGrid llamado cajaDataGridView. Estos datagrid estan enlazados a una base en access como comente. Tambien voy a dejar un codigo que estuve usando en un momento pero que ya no funciona para datagrids enlazados a datos

```
            this.cajaDataGridView.Rows.Add(new string[] {
            Convert.ToString(GridCarro[0, GridCarro.CurrentRow.Index].Value),
            Convert.ToString(GridCarro[1, GridCarro.CurrentRow.Index].Value),
            Convert.ToString(GridCarro[2, GridCarro.CurrentRow.Index].Value),
            Convert.ToString(GridCarro[3, GridCarro.CurrentRow.Index].Value),
            Convert.ToString(GridCarro[4, GridCarro.CurrentRow.Index].Value) });
```

Comment: Podrias poner algo del codigo que has intentado implementar? 
Al primer grid le asignas los datos usando el DataSource, pero el segundo le asignaste datos o solo le defines la estructura de las columnas, o este segundo grid tambien le asignaste datos en el DataSource
Los grids estan en el mismo form?

Comment: SI, los dos estan en el mismo form y los dos datagrid corresponden a dos tablas diferentes de una misma base de datos que la conecte desde el asistente de visual basic. Perdon pero soy nuevo en esto. No tengo codigo ya que probe varias cosas y no me funciono nada

Comment: Tal vez pudieras poner un poco de código (aunque no te funcione) para darnos una idea más clara sobre cuál es en realidad el problema que presentas.

Comment: pero estas tablas tienen la misma estructura de campos ? porque sino no veo que quieres mover, como se relacionan estas tablas, podrias explicar un poco la estructura de campos de cada una y que quieres pasar de una a otra. Evaluaste si esto se puede realizar insertando en la tabla destino con los datos de la tabla origen y luego recargando el grid para actualizarlo

Comment: Puse una imagen de mi form con los DataGrids y un codigo que solo me funciona para DataGrids que no estan enlazados a datos. El programa que tengo que realizar es de control de Stock